# Voting to delete results in a JavaScript error in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, vote-to-delete

On Stack Overflow, I am trying to vote to delete and am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'confirm' of object [object Object] is not a function

I see this in the Chrome console. (Without looking at the console, nothing appears to happen -- for obvious reasons.)

(For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626972/c-sharp-asp-net-ide-tool) question, though I tried a few.)

Comment: What version of chrome? No repro here on Safari 6.0.3 (8536.28.10).

Comment: 25.0.1364.172 m.   And you're right, I tried FireFox and it worked.  (I tried clearing my caches in Chrome, but to no avail)

Comment: Have you voted to delete in the past with chrome? Or is this the first time you've tried deleting?

Comment: Any extensions?

Comment: Not getting this in chrome Dev...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the culprit was a new extension I had installed for Chrome called "Better Pop Up Blocker".  I hadn't considered it because I assumed it only attacked actual new browser windows, not JS alerts.  Stupid of me not to have considered that, but thanks Doorknob for pointing out that possibility.

Apologies -- mods should feel free to close/delete as too localized.  Otherwise I'll leave it up in case it might be a useful signpost for someone in the future.